# Hibernate Validator doesn't work (it allows null values to pass)

Tags: spring, annotations, size, hibernate-validator, notnull

I tried to use the Hibernate Validator but the @NotNull and @Size annotations don't seem to work for me. They allow null values, and values outside defined size pass. Every other Hibernate Validator annotation doesn't work either. Does anyone of you know why? Seemingly everything is okay but still it doesn't work...

Here are my classes, views and xmls, and a link to the whole project if it's needed.

https://www64.zippyshare.com/v/fXFogBpU/file.html

Thank You in advance

**Customer.java**

```
package springdemo.content;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class Customer {

    private String firstName;

    @NotNull(message = "is required")
    @Size(min = 1, message = "is required")
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

**CustomerController.java**

```
package springdemo.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.StringTrimmerEditor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import springdemo.content.Customer;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

    // add an InitBinder to convert and trim input settings
    // remove leading and trailing whitespace
    // resolve issue for our validation

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {

        StringTrimmerEditor stringTrimmerEditor = new StringTrimmerEditor(true);

        dataBinder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, stringTrimmerEditor);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/showForm")
    public String showForm(Model theModel) {

        theModel.addAttribute("customer", new Customer());
        return "customer-form";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/processForm")
    public String processForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("customer") Customer theCustomer,
                              BindingResult theBindingResult) {

        System.out.println("Last name: |" + theCustomer.getLastName() + "|");

        if (theBindingResult.hasErrors()){
            return "customer-form";
        } else {
            return "customer-confirmation";
        }
    }
}
```

**customer-form.jsp**

```
<%--
  Copyright: kuba, 08.01.19 : 19:22
--%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Customer Registration Form</title>

    <style>
        .error {color:red}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<i>Fill out the form. Asterisk (*) means the field is required.</i>
<br><br>

<form:form action="processForm" modelAttribute="customer">

    First name: <form:input path="firstName"/>
    <br><br>

    Last name (*): <form:input path="lastName"/>
    <form:errors path="lastName" cssClass="error"/>
    <br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit data"/>

</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>

    <!-- Spring MVC Configs -->

    <!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>

    <!-- Spring MVC Configs -->

    <!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>learning</groupId>
    <artifactId>springmvcdemo3</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1-b09</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.14.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.14.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-osgi</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.14.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.14.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence-api</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.7</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/joda-time-2.9.7.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/jsoup-1.8.3.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>paranamer</groupId>
            <artifactId>paranamer</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/paranamer-2.8.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>classmate</groupId>
            <artifactId>classmate</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.4</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/classmate-1.3.4.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax-el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax-el</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1-b09</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/javax.el-3.0.1-b09.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jboss-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.Final</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>validation-api</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

For validation to work, Spring framework requires a validator bean to be present. You need to create it in `spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml` as below -

```xml
    <bean id="validator" class="org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator" />
```